# Gevent shows "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'join'"

Tags: python-2.7, gevent

i am new to gevent. While i am running the following code:

```
import gevent

def foo():
  print('Running in foo')
  gevent.sleep(0)
  print('Explicit context switch to foo again')

def bar():
  print('Explicit context to bar')
  gevent.sleep(0)
  print('Implicit context switch back to bar')

gevent.joinall([
gevent.spawn(foo),
gevent.spawn(bar),
])
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ex.py", line 13, in <module>
gevent.join([
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'join'
```

Comment: are you sure the error is not `has no attribute 'joinall'`?

Comment: No. I am continuously getting that error.. @Tim

Comment: Is the code you pasted correct? It says `gevent.joinall([..`, not `join`

Comment: I just ran your code with gevent 1.0.1 and there were no errors, how are you running it?

Comment: I am also using the same version of gevent. But I don't understand why the error is comming.I run it through command line.

Comment: With `python ex.py` as well?

Comment: As pointed out above, the code you posted doesn't match the error message you're getting (`joinall` vs. `join`) so something is wrong.  It might also be worth adding `print(gevent.__file__)` right after `import gevent` to make sure that it's importing the right module.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably getting that error because you're trying to import/call gevent from a file that you happen to have named gevent.py.  Change the name of your file and it should work just fine (assuming you have gevent installed).